# Solved: HP T620 thin client: bizarre boot failure

Tags: linux, boot, installation

Apologies for the length of this post, but the issue is puzzling, and if you keep reading, you will encounter at least 1 astonishing event.

I’ve successfully installed Debian 12 Bookworm on two HP T620 thin clients, but then on the next boot, there are failures that at least *act like* hardware problems. That seems incredible - no way just installing Debian could trash the hardware, right? Besides, others report installing Debian on this model without problems (https://www.parkytowers.me.uk/thin/hp/t620/linux.shtml).

The saga: I bought a T620 on eBay. Some adapters were needed: a PS/2-to-USB adapter for the keyboard, and a DisplayPort 1.2-to-HDMI for the monitor.

I booted it with a USB stick first with Sparky Linux just to see if it worked, then a USB containing debian-12.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso. The non-graphical install option went smoothly. To boot into Debian, 2 further steps were needed: 1. copy /EFI/debian/grubx64.efi to /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi. (Reportedly - see link above - the T620 looks for the .efi file in a nonstandard place), and 2. set BIOS to enable Secure Boot (and disable Legacy Support). Copying the .efi file required booting from a USB drive (Sparky Linux again). After these 2 changes, it booted right up in Debian. I added some users, verified the ssh server. installed a couple utilities, made the IP address static. Finally I shut down (using shutdown -h now).

Next morning, I powered it up. No boot, black screen; the only activity was that the keyboard LEDs flashed twice and numlock stayed on (I had set that in the BIOS), then it emitted beeps and red-LED flashes in groups of 6. No response to repeatedly pressing keys during power-up: F1 (for system info) or F10 (for BIOS setup) or esc (for a “fast test”; not sure if this applies to the T620). The HP manual http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04034585 says that sets of 6 beeps mean “Pre-video graphics error”, and the fix for models with a graphics card is to reseat or replace the graphics card. I tore it down and found that there's no card; graphics are on the motherboard.

Now the astonishing part. I posted a positive review on eBay briefly describing what happened, and saying it wasn’t the seller's fault. 8 days later, another T620 showed up on my doorstep. The vendor evidently saw the review and decided, unasked, to send a replacement!

History repeated itself. Installed Debian from the same .iso. After the successful install, including an XFCE desktop, I shut down. Came back 3-4 hours later, powered up, The same 6 beeps as a week before!! Unplugged all peripherals, same beeps. Removed the RAM card, now instead of 6 beeps it was 5 (meaning “pre-video memory error”). Removed the solid-state disk. Tried booting from the Sparky Linux USB. Beeps in 5's. Reinstalled the RAM card, tried again with Sparky. No beeps. I connected monitor and keyboard. Monitor shows an error (valid) due to no bootable disk. (It can't use Sparky with Legacy Support disabled, and the SSD with Debian was still removed.) It also said press F2 for diagnostics. It passed the Memory Quick Check.

I’m reluctant to power it up again until I have some idea what’s going on. The chance is minuscule that 2 of this computer would coincidentally experience a random hardware failure like this. But somehow it thinks there’s a hardware problem. I just have 1 idea: in the BIOS settings, Power-On Self Test Messages were disabled; I enabled this - mistake? Seems unlikely to be the problem. That, and setting NumLock to be On at startup, are the only BIOS changes I made except the changes needed for Secure Boot.

There is a pushbutton on the motherboard that *I think* resets the BIOS to defaults - anyone know if that’s correct? I guess that’s 1 thing I could try. Good idea?

Thanks for reading to the end; any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Debian 11 "Bullseye" rather than 12 "Bookworm" seems to have resolved everything. Thanks to lewulff on forums.debian.net, who said "there are some differences between how Debian 11 and Debian 12 work with UEFI".

Once Debian 11 was installed, a dist-upgrade to Debian 12 "Bookworm" worked with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the BIOS to 00.02.19 Rev.A, which fixed the beeping without a monitor connected to the machine. With my machine, the beeping only occured when Debian 12 Bookworm was installed and no Monitor was connected. Maybe your Displayport to HDMI adapter was flaky thus producing the same result.

The UEFI "copy to removable media Path" feature can also be selected in the expert installer when installing Grub.

Bios:
[HP T620 Flexible Thin-Client](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp115001-115500/sp115305.exe)